# Send song title to spotify to start playing from android app

Tags: android

Is there any way to send a song title to the spotify app from my app so that it will start playing the song through spotify?

I tried using the bellow code i found in another code but nothing happens.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.setAction(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH);
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.spotify.mobile.android.ui", "com.spotify.mobile.android.ui.Launcher"));
                intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, "michael jackson smooth criminal");
```

I know shazam is able to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are just creating an Intent, but you don't start the Intent.

add this line after setting up your intent

```
startActivity(intent);
```

So the complete code would look like that

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setAction(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.spotify.mobile.android.ui", "com.spotify.mobile.android.ui.Launcher"));
intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, "michael jackson smooth criminal");
try {
  startActivity(intent);
}catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
  Toast.makeText(context, "You must first install Spotify", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
  Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.spotify.mobile.android.ui"));
  startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: Such a stupid mistake I can't believe I missed that, thank you!